# Persist mongodb between invocations in kubernetes on a single-node cluster on windows

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop

I'd like to keep the data in my mongodb when I restart my kubernetes helm chart, but I can't because mongodb fails to start with the following error when the db is mapped to a host path (I'm running on docker desktop):

```
2019-06-23T05:40:35.788+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/opt/bitnami/mongodb/conf/mongodb.conf", net: { bindIpAll: true, ipv6: true, port: 27017, unixDomainSocket: { enabled: true, pathPrefix: "/opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp" } }, processManagement: { fork: false, pidFilePath: "/opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb.pid" }, security: { authorization: "disabled" }, setParameter: { enableLocalhostAuthBypass: "true" }, storage: { dbPath: "/opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: true } }
2019-06-23T05:40:35.791+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=989M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2019-06-23T05:40:37.056+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (17) [1561268437:56536][36:0x7f8cc73279c0], connection: /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists Raw: [1561268437:56536][36:0x7f8cc73279c0], connection: /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists
2019-06-23T05:40:37.063+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message unexpected file WiredTiger.wt found, renamed to WiredTiger.wt.6
2019-06-23T05:40:37.069+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1561268437:69980][36:0x7f8cc73279c0], connection: /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted Raw: [1561268437:69980][36:0x7f8cc73279c0], connection: /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
```

This error is [well known](https://blog.jeremylikness.com/mongodb-on-windows-in-minutes-with-docker-3e412f076762) in the sense that the workaround when running with docker is to create a persistent volume:

```
docker volume create --name=mongodata
```

And then mount that in the mongodb docker container. (I believe the root cause is that HyperV and VirtualBox do not support memory mapped files across the VM boundary).

The problem is that kubernetes has no storage driver for docker volumes (as far as I can tell). So I need another solution. Does anyone have any ideas? I'd love to have it robust enough that it would survive shutdowns of k8/docker and my machine.

I'm running on the latest stable docker desktop on Windows 10 (backed by Hyper V) (v18.09.2). I'm using the Kubernetes that is supplied with it (v1.10.11).

Comment: Hi, how about [Shared drives- settings](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/)
`Share your local drives (volumes) with Docker Desktop for Windows, so that they are available to your Linux containers`

Comment: Shared drives mean doing the mount with a - v on the command line for a Docker start. This mode does not support memory mapped files. Or is there another mode I am missing.

Comment: it seems, this [issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/138) is still in progress. Did you try workarounds provided by community?

Comment: I found also in [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/#platform-specific-considerations): `If you run mongod in a container (e.g. lxc, cgroups, Docker, etc.) that does not have access to all of the RAM available in a system, you must set storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB to a value less than the amount of RAM available in the container. The exact amount depends on the other processes running in the container.`